# Sharepoint Task list and Microsoft Project sync problems

Tags: task-list

I've been using Microsoft Project to sync with a task list on SharePoint, which worked fine for a while, but then suddenly it stopped working saying it's not able to synchronize.

Anyone know what might cause this, or where I could start to look?

Comment: my problem is unwanted sync works fine : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/203496/5170