# unwanted sync on publishing Project Server and random task list in SharePoint farm

Tags: task-list, project-server, sync, synchronisation, ms-project

We designed a portal with SharePoint 2013 and Project 2013 and we have more than 60 custom lists and 10 Doc Libraries and more than 10 thousand items and docs there, but we haven't any tasks list there.

Last month I created tasks list like: **/lists/tasks** , When republished specific project in Project Server, this list synced again and deleted all of the items. (recycle bin didn't work, no versioning but [cmp](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/132311/5170) and backup scenario helped us to revert it back again)

Then I think since "Tasks" is a default SharePoint name in team sites, we created: **/lists/task2** and deleted the last one.

But after **re-Publishing** only one of those projects (specific project), sync fired again, and deleted all items.

Problem is only about one project file in project server, and we have no similar problem about republishing 10 other projects.

We have many timer jobs and event receivers. but I check those E_R with [sharepoint management](https://spm.codeplex.com/) , none of them about [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761977/308578).

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default whenever you publish the Project it will sync all Project Task with SharePoint Task List. In order to stop the sync, you can try below two options.

**1. Unlink SharePoint Site with Project.**

Navigate to Project Server Settings --> Operational Policies --> Connected SharePoint Sites.
[image]

Highlight your Project Plan and click on Edit Site Address. In the pop-up window select "Unlink the SharePoint site from the project." and click ok.

**2. Disable Task Sync via PowerShell.**

You can run below command using SharePoint Shell. Replace http://SITE/PWA/PROJECTSITEURL with Project Site URL for which you would like to disable the task sync.

```
Disable-SPProjectEnterpriseProjectTaskSync -Url http://SITE/PWA/PROJECTSITEURL
```

Comment: thanks , thats right in servername/pwaname/_layouts/15/pwa/Admin/ManageWSS.aspx every project has task list in sharepoint portal that works independently from project workspaces and its lists

Comment: Disabling the Sync will not cause any issue related to permission but that list won't update post disabling.