# Tasks do not disappear from My Tasks list

Tags: task-list, sharepoint-server

Has anyone an idea why tasks do not disappear from the My Tasks list?

In our SharePoint environment many task lists exit for our users. Most users use their own My Tasks list to maintain the tasks assigned to them. When a task is marked as complete in the original task list or in My Tasks, the task is updated and disappears from the My Tasks list.

But sometimes tasks are deleted from the original task list and keep existing in the My Tasks list. Trying to mark that task as complete in the My Tasks list does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how I can re-sync these lists?

I already deleted the user profile and created it again, but that did not help.

Comment: Are there any filters added on the list view in which the tasks are disappearing??

Comment: @GaneshSanap The My Tasks list is the task list that can be found in the personal About Me site. This list has views but cannot be changed by a user. The default view shows all tasks assinged to the user. I personnally think that by deleting the task from the original list a link is broken with the My Tasks list that needs to be repaired.

Comment: Are you deleting the tasks from original list?

Comment: Yes, sometimes users delete tasks from the original task list. These deleted tasks remain visible in the My Tasks list.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, task item is not deleted in my task when item deleted in SharePoint task list.

Per my test, it will sync the task list item to my site tasks list everyone 5 minutes by a timer job.

Does your task comes from project site?

You can click edit and then delete the task:

[image]

Reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f4eec5be-bfca-4342-8578-0c508cdcd5b7/task-item-is-not-deleted-in-my-task-when-item-deleted-in-sharepoint-task-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment

[unwanted sync on publishing Project Server and random task list in SharePoint farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203496/unwanted-sync-on-publishing-project-server-and-random-task-list-in-sharepoint-fa)

Comment: Hi Lisa, thank you for your answer. 

If I click Edit of that specific task, the message ‘Something went wrong’ is shown.

I looked into both links you send me and found two timer jobs related to tasks. The timer jobs ‘Workflow Auto Cleanup’ and ‘Bulk workflow task processing’ both run daily. 

Neither in de sites you mentioned nor in our SharePoint I can find any other timer jobs related to tasks. Do I miss something? What I do see is that if a My Task list is opened, it will update only every 5 minutes.

The original task lists are located in subsites, like project sites.